# Azure Customer Identities in own Tenant?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

If you manage accounts for your customers and want to continue to do so, do you move them to the same tenant where your normal accounts are or do you move them to a dedicated tenant and do B2B?

Comment: I think the main question there is: Do you want/need to manage their passwords etc.? If yes, move them to your tenant or another dedicated tenant. If you only need to give them access to apps in your tenant, then you can add them as guests with B2B.

Comment: Customer accounts should remain under own control (passwords etc.). So the question is same or dedicated tenant?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-admin-add-users#add-guest-users-to-the-directory) link for how to add guest users to your own tenant.

Your external users can be added as guests and you can then manage them in your own tenant.

[image]

Comment: This is how it works if you would move them to a dedicated tenant to enable B2B or use the accounts of their own tenants (e.g. from company A, B, C etc.). My question is around when you want to keep complete control, do you have the customer accounts in your tenant or a dedicated an do B2B to federated them into your tenant.